# Segue to view controller after while loop

Tags: arrays, swift, segue

I apologize in advance because I am very new to swift. I have an array of strings (answerSet) that pop up randomly and without repeating when a view controller is tapped. I did this through a while loop and added an if statement so once the last string in the array pops up the user can tap the screen and it triggers a segue to go to the next view controller (toEnd). This doesn't work properly as a couple strings occur when the screen is tapped but then the segue is triggered before all the strings in the array have been shown. I have provided the code. Please let me know how to fix this and thanks so much!  PM.png[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjcOv.png)

Comment: Don't post code in screenshots. Add them as actual text in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the element in `answerSet` rather than setting it to an empty string.

```
answerSet.remove(at: randomIndex)
```

Without this, it can trigger the segue if on the next loop the `randomIndex` gets an empty string.

Comment: thanks for answering. So then for the while loop I would say while (answerSet > 0) {

Comment: The way it is at the minute, your `while` loop doesn’t seem to do anything that an `if else` loop would not. Is the `while` loop even necessary? If you post your code as text I’ll type something up.

Comment: @Pablo Can you post our code as text? I’m happy to try to help.